# Ruby on Rails multidimensional array-like storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a form that has:

*TextInput*--Skill

*DropDown*--Years Experience

Using jQuery, I have the input and drop down fields populate if a user has more skills to add. Is it possible to store many sets of skills and their respective years experience in a database entry?

I've been looking into has_many:

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for extra query here (has_many), look into rails serialization:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences, Hash
end

user = User.create(:preferences => { "background" => "black", "display" => "large" })
User.find(user.id).preferences # => { "background" => "black", "display" => "large" }
```

You can do the same with Array

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense, but I'm confused as to how to change multiple fields into the create method, I think that's where most of my troubles lie.

Comment: well, since you're using jquery anyways, you could add the hidden_field to your form and bind the .submit event to it. Once user submits the form, jquery will populate that field with all the [skill, experience] values ( in whatever format you like ). So you'll then have to parse it in your controller